# angularjs display expression dynamically from controller value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am bad at explaining i hope you guys understand my requirements and help me out here.

I have a view with ng-repeat below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allitems"> {{displaydata}} </div>
```

i have a controller with below data

```
$scope.allitems ={
1:{name:"car",price:"999",qty:8},
2:{name:"bag",price:"127",qty:2},
3:{name:"dog",price:"777",qty:3},
4:{name:"cat",price:"333",qty:4}
}
var displaychoice1 = "{{item.name}}" 
var displaychoice2 = "{{item.price}}"
$scope.displaydata = "I want " + displaychoice1 + " which cost " + displaychoice2 ;
```

I want users to be able to select the "fields" to output to the view instead of hardcoding what to display in the view.

Comment: well then just go with `<div ng-repeat="item in allitems">I want {{item.name}} which cost {{item.name}}</div>`

Or what exactly do you need?

Comment: this `ng-repeat` wouldn't even work as written;  this pattern is invalid for objects.  `allitems` would have to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.allitems` should be an `array`

```
$scope.allitems = [
  {name:"car",price:"999",qty:8},
  {name:"bag",price:"127",qty:2},
  {name:"dog",price:"777",qty:3},
  {name:"cat",price:"333",qty:4}
]
```

And on the html you can simply

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allitems">
  I want {{item.name}} which cost {{item.price}}
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Allowing users to select fields could be something like

On controller:

```
$scope.displaydata = function(item, field1, field2){
  return "I want " + item[field1] + " which cost " + item[field2]; 
}
```

On HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allitems">
   {{ displaydata(item, 'name', 'price') }}
 </div>
```

Where you could adapt `name` and `price` to come from variables you have

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngoptions for it to allow user to select an option:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="item in allitems track by $index"
      ng-model="selectedOption">  </select>

I want {{selectedOption.name}} which cost {{selectedOption.price}}
```